# Dummy Output in 20.04 - works after reinstall but not after reboot

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

**The Problem:**

My 20.04 sound system is **bunk**. It only shows dummy output as a sink I can use. It does detect my USB Microphone and Internal Microphone However.

**A big Hint:**

though odd - It works after uninstall/reinstall of pulseaudio and alsa-base ...

```
apt-get install --reinstall alsa-base pulseaudio
```

*perfectly*. Then *irritatingly* after reboot, goes back to dummy.

**$inxi -SMA**

```
System:    Host: DoomMachine Kernel: 5.9.0-050900-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Gnome 3.36.4 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Convertible System: HP product: HP ENVY x360 Convertible 15m-ee0xxx 
           v: Type1ProductConfigId serial: <superuser/root required> 
           Mobo: HP model: 876F v: 13.31 serial: <superuser/root required> UEFI: Insyde v: F.07 
           date: 06/02/2020 
Audio:     Device-1: AMD driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Device-2: AMD Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor driver: snd_rn_pci_acp3x 
           Device-3: AMD Family 17h HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Device-4: JMTek LLC. USB PnP Audio Device type: USB 
           driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.9.0-050900-generic
```

I did some diffs before and after to try and characterize the problem
the **before** is on left **after** on right

```
                                                       >    0   auto_null.monitor   module-null-sink.c  s16le
1   alsa_input.usb-0c76_USB_PnP_Audio_Device-00.mono-fall   1   alsa_input.usb-0c76_USB_PnP_Audio_Device-00.mono-fall
2   alsa_input.pci-0000_04_00.5-platform-acp_pdm_mach.0.s   2   alsa_input.pci-0000_04_00.5-platform-acp_pdm_mach.0.s
3   alsa_output.pci-0000_04_00.6.HiFi__hw_Generic_1__sink <
4   alsa_input.pci-0000_04_00.6.HiFi__hw_acp__source      <
5   alsa_input.pci-0000_04_00.6.HiFi__hw_Generic_1__sourc <
```

I also don't seem to be using alsa-base.conf or blacklist.conf
because I moved both to test, and the result stayed the same.

any ideas would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Please don't put [SOLVED] in the question title in this site. The green check mark in the accepted answer below is sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has happened to me on my Linux Mint device after the update.

What I found was that it was caused by the alsa-lib package update, in detail the libasound2 libasound2-data libatopology2 dependencies upgrade.

I found the solution here:

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=334345

This should also work on other Debian devices.

**TLDR;**
for now you can revert back to older version of the package to fix the sound before the bug is patched by alsa-lib devs.

Use command:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install libasound2=1.2.2-2.1 libasound2-data=1.2.2-2.1 libatopology2=1.2.2-2.1
```

Comment: This totally worked!
Thank you so much!